# Insert dot symbol into a string number

Tags: c#, .net

I have int variables, example:

```
int money = 1234567890;
```

How I can insert "." into money, and make its format like this:

```
1.234.567.890
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
var text = money.ToString("N0",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de"));
```

The result is:

```
1.234.567.890
```

(I just picked the German culture as I knew they use `.` for the separator.)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator.aspx):

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false ).NumberFormat;
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
Int64 myInt = 1234567890;
Console.WriteLine( myInt.ToString( "N", nfi ) );
```

([Link to ideone.](http://ideone.com/Z7O5Ou))

Answer (score 4):

To get exactly the format, use

```
int money = 1234567890;
money.ToString(@"#\.###\.###\.##0");
```

More information on custom formats [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx). You need to escape the dot because otherwise the first one will be interpreted as the decimal one. 0 in the end is necessary if you want to display it for zero values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "Money' format try:

```
    int money = 1234567890;
    string moneyString = String.Format("{0:C}", money);
```

returns "$1,234,567,890.00"

Im not sure what money format uses '.' instead of ',' but that could just be a globalization thing.